# Type safe event/messaging system

Tags: c++, oop, events, design-patterns, messaging

I have been recently trying to design e generic and easily extensible event/messaging system in C++, but i run to the following problems:

- How can it be designed in a type safe manner?
- How can it be really extensible and decoupled while following question #1?
- Is object oriented paradigm a good choice for this kind of problem?

This all started by trying to make a messaging system similar to the one that WinAPI depends on (a message/event id and 2 generic parameters that are being cast from the client of the system to the appropriate type according to the event), but i could not find any design/pattern/idiom to make it type safe. Whatever solution i thought somewhere it relied on some type of casting that according to many opinions does not confront with the Object Oriented Paradigm.

Could someone tell me if this kind of system can be designed using a static languages as C++,
and if so, how?

Also is casting "bad" and avoidable in all situations with the usage of a better Design, or there are cases that casting is unavoidable?

Comment: How about using templates?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  How could i use them in a situation like this?

Comment: And how about [boost.signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2.html)?

Comment: You can also combine a ready solution [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) with a type-safe and platform-independent serialization, such as [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/), and voila

Comment: Messaging systems are a kind of double-dispatch problem.  We want uniform processing of messages (and message categories) with polymorphic state within each message, and polymorphic handling of messages.  We even want to be able to define new kinds of messages (and assign them to categories) and handle them far away.  So look up double-dispatch solutions?

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov nice find on msgpack!